# Would denouncing cheaters from an exam make me less likely to receive penalties?

Tags: cheating

I aced my undergrad studies and got the best offer I could ever dream of for grad school.

And three **** might have ruined it.

They ran into me and asked for help with "studying". Turns out it was blatant cheating and I helped them anyway. I had my doubts, but my compassion instinct took ever.

I'm looking forward pursuing an academic career, and I don't think this event was good at all. It's nowhere near loving my sleep over this issue, but I want to keep my academic integrity and cover my ass.

Now, if the punishment for cheating was just a failed exam, I would've denounced without hesitation. But in my country, you can get banned for exams and higher education for 5 years. I think it's enough to destroy someone's life. At the same time, they (the 3 ****) put mine on the line so they could pass some exam. (If they get caught and I somehow get involved, I can get banned for 5 years too. Everything I worked for 3 years, gone in an instant)

I'm about to send the email to the equivalent of the Dean, but I just can't know for sure if I'll stay safe. I know him kinda personally and have friends that are friends with him, but still, I'm scared and I fucked up.

What should I do?

Edit:

Here's a rundown of the events

- I ate at school self, not my usual spot
- The 3 **** ran into me. They asked me to help them with studying and I accepted. I had doubts that it was a cheating scheme but paid no mind to it.
- A few hours later, they send me a photo, there were some questions and I assumed it was an exam from previous years. I asked them when was the exam and they said "now lol". Doubts that it was a cheating scheme were almost confirmed. I answered these questions and sent the answers anyway because I was pressured from holding an unwritten contract and instinctual compassion
- They sent another photo, I saw the date of the exam and it was the day all of these events happened. I stopped communications.
- And here we are now. I helped them cheat and I want to pursue an academic career. This is like a big stain I'd like to clean.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how this scheme worked exactly?

Comment: Yes I can. They asked me to help them with a study group. Being hardwired with compassion I accepted. They sent photos, I answered. They send other photos and I see : 'Exam of today' and I cut communications. However I had doubts they were cheating and did not try to get it out of them.

Comment: Talk to the instructor. But first gather some evidence that they indeed let you on, eg. the request for a "study group".

Comment: I will eventually. I'm still afraid I could be held liable.

Comment: They had a stolen copy of the exam to come? I don't see how this is help in cheating if you answer their questions. If you knowingly saw the exam, then *you* have cheated also!

Comment: They had a stolen copy of the exam. But they framed the photo for me not to see the date of the exam. I assumed it was an exam from past years.

Comment: So you've also cheated on that exam. Doesn't matter if you wanted to. My advice comes in four words: "Keep your mouth shut!". And hope those others pass the exam, so they will never rat on you. The best that could happen would be you having to re-take the exam.

Comment: I didn't even take the exam. This is just sad.

Comment: Please put all this info into the question.

Comment: Done @Karl !!!!

Comment: I don't get why you say you had doubts about cheating before you saw the date. Did you actually already think they had stolen it? Anyway, you didn't cheat, you didn't steal, you just answered their questions. Tell your dean you later noticed the date stamp to be todays, why should he doubt you if you weren't supposed to take that exam youself?

Comment: I had doubts because we were in exam periods, I had already done mine. I have no idea how to got the exam paper. I also had doubts because these 3 were not known to be very bright or motivated. I still asked BEFORE sending the answers when was the exam and they said it was now. At this point doubts were almost confirmed but as I said, I was pressured by compassion and sent it anyway.

Comment: That's not compassion.  Compassion would have been "Huh. I need to think about this, but I'm in the middle of something else right now. Let me get back to you in a few hours."

Comment: What was it then?

Answer (score 4):

Talk to someone you can trust.

The rules in your place seem to be very severe. Therefore, I advice you not only to listen to people in this forum, but to consult someone who knows the rules in your country. In my other answer, I recommended ombudswomen/ombudsmen or the student union. As in your country, you can be banned from higher education for 5 years, I would advise you to talk to a lawyer. Let them advise you.

In most places, the best way would be to "confess". However, if in your place it is possible to get punished for five years for what you did (which is in my eyes no misdeed at all, as you did not know you helped cheaters) there may be more messed up rules/strange things going on. So please, for your own sake, consult a lawyer (or similar), good luck!

(And yes, of course consult the institution rules and try to find out if similar cases happend before.)

Comment: I asked a friend to seek advice to a professor. He (the professor message relayed by my friend) told me to snitch without hesitation. I'd like to do that only if it clears me from any accusation... which I'm not certain it would. These rules are messed up in my opinion, I better tread carefully. I'll ask around seeking advice from people who are in my country. Thank you.

Comment: @truvaking: I would absolutely not take advice by a professor. It is definitely not clear if what they say is in your interest.

Answer (score 2):

Aiding people to cheat is the same as cheating in many institutions which is why is it usually part of the policy at the respective institution...

Do consider that you may well face consequences for your part in this situation.

What the consequences will be is something your institution will decide - we cannot guess...

Comment: That is just great... I'll consult the institution rules.

Comment: Depends strongly on the kind of cheating, don't you think? *Compiling* a cheat sheet is not a crime, taking it into the exam is!

Comment: @Karl having your compiled cheat sheet fall out of your pocket during the exam is cheating, but outside the exam room it is clearly just revision material...